# Xcode 4.3 Core Data how to make a list?

Tags: nsmutablearray, save, xcode4.3

I am new to iOS development (and objective-C & Xcode 4.3) and I want to create an app with profiles for users. I understand how to use Core Data to make a table with entities and that's all fine, but I don't know how I would go about creating a model so that a user can save a list of items (ie a MutableArray).

For example I need to have a username (for the profile) and than a list of strings that are saved to his account.

Would I need to  just create an table with username and string item and than just query for all tuples that contain the username. Is there a simple way to serialize an object and save it the same way it's done in java.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a one-to-many relationship (which makes a NSSet of "destination" objects, or if you want to keep them in the specified order, click Ordered and it will be a NSOrderedSet).

Once you have the relationship, you can add multiple items to it and access it via the set.